# D3.js append circle to the GROUP based on the JSON value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here I'm getting json data as

```
{
"nodes": [{
    "name": "Tomcat",
    "comp_type": "tomcat_155:7077",
    "id": "tomcat_155:7077",
    "pie": true,
    "url": "../images/component_icons/1424962275_f-server_128.svg",
    "group": 1,
    "fixed": true
}, {
    "name": "lraj_155_Nov_3(MS SQL)",
    "comp_type": "192.168.11.212:1433_Ba",
    "id": "lraj_155_Nov_3(MS SQL)",
    "pie": false,
    "url": "../images/component_icons/1424962160_19.svg",
    "group": 2,
    "fixed": true
}, {
    "name": "rajesh_window",
    "comp_type": "192.234.11.116:1433_window",
    "id": "rajesh_window",
    "pie": false,
    "url": "../images/component_icons/1424882359_database.svg",
    "group": 3,
    "fixed": true
}, {
    "name": "shanker_ux_win_3(PS)",
    "comp_type": "192.168.11.116:1433_window",
    "pie": true,
    "id": "shanker_ux_win_3(PS)",
    "url": "../images/component_icons/1424882359_database.svg",
    "group": 4,
    "fixed": true
}],
"links": [{
    "source": 1,
    "target": 0,
    "description": "windows flows",
    "value": 1
}, {
    "source": 2,
    "description": "SQLMS(36.67%)",
    "target": 0,
    "value": 8
}, {
    "source": 1,
    "description": "",
    "target": 0,
    "value": 8
}, {
    "source": 3,
    "target": 2,
    "description": "ctrix 6765",
    "value": 1
}]
```

}

Each node contains PIE which is true or false.
So when i render d3 force layout, If PIE is true a circle have to append to group else no circle have to append.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a filter. For example, assuming that you append a `g` element for each datum and circles only for those for which `pie == true`:

```
d3.selectAll("g").data(json.nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .filter(function(d) { return d.pie; })
  .append("circle");
```